# Kohana: Using auth module of php-activerecord, but seeing error as " Class 'Arm' not found"

Tags: authentication, kohana, php, phpactiverecord

I am using PHP-activerecord in kohana and using its auth module by calling function :

```
User::create_user("Name", "Name", "Name", "Name");
```

But seeing error : ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Arm' not found

I have added kohana-activerecord in bootstrap.php and also enabled Auth module. arm.php is in kohana-activerecord/classes/.

Can someone please help understand how to locate Class arm and remove this error. This will be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using https://github.com/devi/kohana-activerecord, the simplest answer is to load the class manually.

`require_once('/kohana-activerecord/classes/arm.php')` in your code, and do that until you have all of your dependencies loaded.  I'm not entirely sure how the Kohana-Auth library is meant to load properly, and it has no real useful documentation on its github page.  But I'll assume just manually loading the classes will be fine as it hasn't been updated for a couple years.

Comment: yes, loading it manually and it worked. Can you also help understand how to call functions of class Kohana_Auth_Arm?? All auth functions are in there which i directly want to use? Thanks in advance.